# Unable to assign data to Worksheet.TypeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am a newbie to openpyxl for writing data to excel. I am actually developing a script that scrap data from a dynamic website and save it to excel. Following is the code for saving data to excel worksheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

try:
    wb = Workbook("MyData.xlsx") #Open Existing workbook

except:
    wb = load_workbook("MyData.xlsx") #Open Existing workbook


wb.create_sheet("Trip Details")  # Creating a Worksheet
trips_ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Trip Details")

row = 1
column = 0

trips_ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20
trips_ws.column_dimensions['F'].width = 40
trips_ws.column_dimensions['G'].width = 40

trips_ws['A1'] = 'Date'
trips_ws['B1'] = "Time"
trips_ws['C1'] = "Fare"
trips_ws['D1'] =  "TripTime"
trips_ws['E1'] =  "Distance"
trips_ws['G1'] =  "PICKUP"
trips_ws['H1'] =  "DROP"
```

But this is showing me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition  
2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script

File "C:/Users/manje_000/PycharmProjects/test\Add2Excel.py", line 54, in Add_to_excel
trips_ws['A1'] = 'Date'
TypeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object does not support item assignment
```

have searched for this a lot, but couldn't find anything. Can anyone tell what is the issue, despite following the correct procedure.

Answer (score 3):

The Issue is the line

```
wb = Workbook("MyData.xlsx") #Open Existing workbook
```

You could not open a existing workbook using `class Workbook(...)`.
The only Parameter are `class Workbook(write_only=True|False)`.

Try without string: `wb = Workbook()`

[From the Docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode):
**In a write-only workbook, rows can only be added with append(). It is not possible to write (or read) cells at arbitrary locations with cell() or iter_rows().**

**If you want to add data to a existing workbook:**

Example to add a Worksheet to an existing Workbook and
write the string 'Date' into cell 'A1'

```
wb = load_workbook("MyData.xlsx") #Open Existing workbook
trips_ws = wb.create_sheet("Trip Details")  # Append a new Worksheet  
trips_ws['A1'] = 'Date'
wb.save("MyData.xlsx")
```

Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.

Comment: This is covered by the `try… except` block. We must assume the code is incomplete.

Comment: Tried this without `try… except` block, `class Workbook` does not complain about `String` Value. Debug tells `Workbook.write_only="MyData.xlsx"`.  So he is getting a `WriteOnlyWorksheet`.

Comment: Thanks Stovfl for your reply. But i want to add that i want to open existing workbook to save data. I belevie what you have suggested will create a new one.

Comment: Also i tried what you said, in that case, it is not showing any error but still also not adding any data to the file